# How to compile CUDA SDK Sample?

Tags: sdk, cuda

I failed to compile conjugate gradient solver. I downloaded the whole archieve that contains libraries, makefile and other stuff but the compiler lacks some header files. How to include all files I downloaded? Maybe I need to add some path or copy folder "common" to `/usr/local/cuda/include/`

Comment: Do you have cuda 5 installed on your machine?  Normally the samples get installed at `/usr/local/cuda/samples` and it should be pretty easy to compile if you have root access, you should be able to just go to that directory and type `make`.  The necessary include paths should already be in the Makefile if you have a proper cuda 5 install.  If you read the "verify the installation" section of the [getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html), it discusses how to make all the samples, even without root access.

Comment: Yes, I have CUDA 5.0 but I don't have folder "samples" at /usr/local/cuda/

Comment: Did you do the cuda install or did someone else do it?  Probably the easiest way to proceed is to re-install cuda 5 and select "Yes" when prompted to install the samples, rather than "no".  Or perhaps they were installed at some other path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To download and build a cuda sample directly, the following steps worked for me:

```
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/CUDALibraries/Projects/x64/conjugateGradient.tar.gz
tar -xzvf conjugateGradient.tar.gz
cd 7_CUDALibraries/conjugateGradient
make
# to execute the program:
./conjugateGradient
```

This assumes a standard cuda 5 install is available at `/usr/local/cuda`. 
It does not assume that any samples are previously installed.
I tested this on a machine with CUDA 5 and RHEL 5.5

If this does not work, please post details of the error output you received.

If you want to use some other sample than the example given here, the download links can be obtained [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html).

Comment: I followed all steps but it gives me: max@max-Lenovo-G560:~/7_CUDALibraries/conjugateGradient$ make
g++ -m32  -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I. -I.. -I../../common/inc -o main.o -c main.cpp
In file included from /usr/local/cuda/include/deal.II/base/memory_consumption.h:17:0,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/helper_functions.h:19,
                 from main.cpp:29:
/usr/local/cuda/include/deal.II/base/std_cxx1x/shared_ptr.h:32:32: fatal error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp: this file doesn't exist

Comment: Actually, I tried to modify the code to avoid using cudaCheckErrors and all the stuff concerned with statistics about the GPU device. Now it compiles correctly

Comment: what is `/usr/local/cuda/include/deal.ll`  ??  I don't have that.  It's not part of cuda 5.  Also, the build should be picking up `helper_functions.h` from `../../common/inc` not from `/usr/local/cuda/include`.   CUDA 5 has no `helper_functions.h` in `/usr/local/cuda/include`.   You have a strange CUDA 5 setup.