# Cannot create context on NVIDIA device with ECC enabled

Tags: cuda, nvidia, cuda-context

On a node with 4 NVIDIA GPUs I enabled on device 0 the ECC memory protection (all other have ECC disabled). Since I enabled ECC on device 0 my application (CUDA, using just one device) hangs when it tries to create the context on this device 0 (driver API). I don't know why it hangs at that point. If I use a different device setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICE accordingly to another device it works fine. It must have to do with enabling ECC. Any thoughts?
Here the output of `nvidia-smi`:
(Why does it report 99% volatile GPU utilization, nothing is running there?)

```
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 4.304.54   Driver Version: 304.54         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                     | Bus-Id        Disp.  | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage         | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K20m               | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                    1 |
| N/A   29C    P0    49W / 225W |   0%   12MB / 4799MB |     99%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla K20m               | 0000:03:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   22C    P8    15W / 225W |   0%   12MB / 4799MB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla K20m               | 0000:83:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   22C    P8    24W / 225W |   0%   11MB / 4799MB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla K20m               | 0000:84:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   23C    P8    25W / 225W |   0%   11MB / 4799MB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running compute processes found                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

EDIT: `nvidia-smi -a` reports ECC enabled on all devices. Strange!

```
==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                       : Fri Apr 26 10:18:14 2013
Driver Version                  : 304.54

Attached GPUs                   : 4
GPU 0000:02:00.0
    Product Name                : Tesla K20m
    Display Mode                : Disabled
    Persistence Mode            : Enabled
    Driver Model
        Current                 : N/A
        Pending                 : N/A
    Serial Number               : 0324512044699
    VBIOS Version               : 80.10.11.00.0B
    Inforom Version
        Image Version           : 2081.0208.01.07
        OEM Object              : 1.1
        ECC Object              : 3.0
        Power Management Object : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                 : Compute
        Pending                 : Compute
    PCI
        Bus                     : 0x02
        Device                  : 0x00
        Domain                  : 0x0000
        Device Id               : 0x102810DE
        Bus Id                  : 0000:02:00.0
        Sub System Id           : 0x101510DE
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max             : 2
                Current         : 2
            Link Width
                Max             : 16x
                Current         : 16x
    Fan Speed                   : N/A
    Performance State           : P0
    Clocks Throttle Reasons
        Idle                    : Not Active
        User Defined Clocks     : Not Active
        SW Power Cap            : Not Active
        HW Slowdown             : Not Active
        Unknown                 : Not Active
    Memory Usage
        Total                   : 4799 MB
        Used                    : 12 MB
        Free                    : 4787 MB
    Compute Mode                : Default
    Utilization
        Gpu                     : 99 %
        Memory                  : 0 %
    Ecc Mode
        Current                 : Enabled
        Pending                 : Enabled
    ECC Errors
        Volatile
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory   : 1
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 1
        Aggregate
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory   : 1
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 1
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
    Temperature
        Gpu                     : 29 C
    Power Readings
        Power Management        : Supported
        Power Draw              : 49.51 W
        Power Limit             : 225.00 W
        Default Power Limit     : 225.00 W
        Min Power Limit         : 150.00 W
        Max Power Limit         : 225.00 W
    Clocks
        Graphics                : 758 MHz
        SM                      : 758 MHz
        Memory                  : 2600 MHz
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                : 705 MHz
        Memory                  : 2600 MHz
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                : 758 MHz
        SM                      : 758 MHz
        Memory                  : 2600 MHz
    Compute Processes           : None

GPU 0000:03:00.0
    Product Name                : Tesla K20m
    Display Mode                : Disabled
    Persistence Mode            : Enabled
    Driver Model
        Current                 : N/A
        Pending                 : N/A
    Serial Number               : 0324512044821
    VBIOS Version               : 80.10.11.00.0B
    Inforom Version
        Image Version           : 2081.0208.01.07
        OEM Object              : 1.1
        ECC Object              : 3.0
        Power Management Object : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                 : Compute
        Pending                 : Compute
    PCI
        Bus                     : 0x03
        Device                  : 0x00
        Domain                  : 0x0000
        Device Id               : 0x102810DE
        Bus Id                  : 0000:03:00.0
        Sub System Id           : 0x101510DE
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max             : 2
                Current         : 1
            Link Width
                Max             : 16x
                Current         : 16x
    Fan Speed                   : N/A
    Performance State           : P8
    Clocks Throttle Reasons
        Idle                    : Active
        User Defined Clocks     : Not Active
        SW Power Cap            : Not Active
        HW Slowdown             : Not Active
        Unknown                 : Not Active
    Memory Usage
        Total                   : 4799 MB
        Used                    : 12 MB
        Free                    : 4787 MB
    Compute Mode                : Default
    Utilization
        Gpu                     : 0 %
        Memory                  : 0 %
    Ecc Mode
        Current                 : Enabled
        Pending                 : Enabled
    ECC Errors
        Volatile
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
        Aggregate
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
    Temperature
        Gpu                     : 19 C
    Power Readings
        Power Management        : Supported
        Power Draw              : 15.22 W
        Power Limit             : 225.00 W
        Default Power Limit     : 225.00 W
        Min Power Limit         : 150.00 W
        Max Power Limit         : 225.00 W
    Clocks
        Graphics                : 324 MHz
        SM                      : 324 MHz
        Memory                  : 324 MHz
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                : 705 MHz
        Memory                  : 2600 MHz
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                : 758 MHz
        SM                      : 758 MHz
        Memory                  : 2600 MHz
    Compute Processes           : None

GPU 0000:83:00.0
    Product Name                : Tesla K20m
    Display Mode                : Disabled
    Persistence Mode            : Enabled
    Driver Model
        Current                 : N/A
        Pending                 : N/A
    Serial Number               : 0324512044783
    VBIOS Version               : 80.10.11.00.0B
    Inforom Version
        Image Version           : 2081.0208.01.07
        OEM Object              : 1.1
        ECC Object              : 3.0
        Power Management Object : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                 : Compute
        Pending                 : Compute
    PCI
        Bus                     : 0x83
        Device                  : 0x00
        Domain                  : 0x0000
        Device Id               : 0x102810DE
        Bus Id                  : 0000:83:00.0
        Sub System Id           : 0x101510DE
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max             : 2
                Current         : 1
            Link Width
                Max             : 16x
                Current         : 16x
    Fan Speed                   : N/A
    Performance State           : P8
    Clocks Throttle Reasons
        Idle                    : Active
        User Defined Clocks     : Not Active
        SW Power Cap            : Not Active
        HW Slowdown             : Not Active
        Unknown                 : Not Active
    Memory Usage
        Total                   : 4799 MB
        Used                    : 11 MB
        Free                    : 4788 MB
    Compute Mode                : Default
    Utilization
        Gpu                     : 0 %
        Memory                  : 0 %
    Ecc Mode
        Current                 : Enabled
        Pending                 : Enabled
    ECC Errors
        Volatile
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
        Aggregate
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
    Temperature
        Gpu                     : 22 C
    Power Readings
        Power Management        : Supported
        Power Draw              : 24.74 W
        Power Limit             : 225.00 W
        Default Power Limit     : 225.00 W
        Min Power Limit         : 150.00 W
        Max Power Limit         : 225.00 W
    Clocks
        Graphics                : 324 MHz
        SM                      : 324 MHz
        Memory                  : 324 MHz
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                : 705 MHz
        Memory                  : 2600 MHz
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                : 758 MHz
        SM                      : 758 MHz
        Memory                  : 2600 MHz
    Compute Processes           : None

GPU 0000:84:00.0
    Product Name                : Tesla K20m
    Display Mode                : Disabled
    Persistence Mode            : Enabled
    Driver Model
        Current                 : N/A
        Pending                 : N/A
    Serial Number               : 0324512044628
    VBIOS Version               : 80.10.11.00.0B
    Inforom Version
        Image Version           : 2081.0208.01.07
        OEM Object              : 1.1
        ECC Object              : 3.0
        Power Management Object : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                 : Compute
        Pending                 : Compute
    PCI
        Bus                     : 0x84
        Device                  : 0x00
        Domain                  : 0x0000
        Device Id               : 0x102810DE
        Bus Id                  : 0000:84:00.0
        Sub System Id           : 0x101510DE
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max             : 2
                Current         : 1
            Link Width
                Max             : 16x
                Current         : 16x
    Fan Speed                   : N/A
    Performance State           : P8
    Clocks Throttle Reasons
        Idle                    : Active
        User Defined Clocks     : Not Active
        SW Power Cap            : Not Active
        HW Slowdown             : Not Active
        Unknown                 : Not Active
    Memory Usage
        Total                   : 4799 MB
        Used                    : 11 MB
        Free                    : 4788 MB
    Compute Mode                : Default
    Utilization
        Gpu                     : 0 %
        Memory                  : 0 %
    Ecc Mode
        Current                 : Enabled
        Pending                 : Enabled
    ECC Errors
        Volatile
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
        Aggregate
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory   : 0
                Register File   : 0
                L1 Cache        : 0
                L2 Cache        : 0
                Texture Memory  : 0
                Total           : 0
    Temperature
        Gpu                     : 23 C
    Power Readings
        Power Management        : Supported
        Power Draw              : 25.47 W
        Power Limit             : 225.00 W
        Default Power Limit     : 225.00 W
        Min Power Limit         : 150.00 W
        Max Power Limit         : 225.00 W
    Clocks
        Graphics                : 324 MHz
        SM                      : 324 MHz
        Memory                  : 324 MHz
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                : 705 MHz
        Memory                  : 2600 MHz
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                : 758 MHz
        SM                      : 758 MHz
        Memory                  : 2600 MHz
    Compute Processes           : None
```

Comment: Did you reboot after turning ECC on?  the act of running `nvidia-smi` can generate "phantom" utilization on one of the GPUs.

Comment: Issuing `nvidia-smi -i 0 --ecc-config=1` enabled ECC and required a reboot to take effect. Yes, I rebooted the node

Comment: can you run the bandwidthTest cuda sample on device 0 (or all of the devices)?

Comment: also, can you paste the results of `nvidia-smi -a` into the question

Comment: I seem to have not installed the CUDA examples. What it a quick way to build `bandwidthTest`?

Comment: nvidia-smi is reporting a double-bit (uncorrectable) ECC error on the device 0.  That may cause the device to be unusable for new cuda context creation until you reboot the system.  I would issue the `nvidia-smi` command to reset volatile and non-volatile errors on device 0, then reboot the system, then run `nvidia-smi -a` again.  If device 0 is reporting 0 ECC errors, then try to run a cuda sample or your app again.

Comment: Ok, I will do this. Why is `nvidia-smi -a` reporting ECC enabled on device 1,2,3 while `nvidia-smi` in overview mode reports it disabled? Or am I interpreting the output incorrectly?

Comment: The summary view is reporting that the other devices have not had errors, if ECC is disabled the "Volatile Uncorr. ECC" field will say N/A.

Comment: You can download any sample from [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html).  I give a complete example of how to build one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790150/how-to-compile-cuda-sdk-sample/15791386#15791386)

Comment: Well spotted! Thanks Robert!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nvidia-smi output shows an uncorrectable ECC error on the device. You can reset the error using `nvidia-smi --reset-ecc-errors=0 -g 0` and retry. The `0` in the reset indicates to reset the volatile counter only, the aggregate counter will still indicate that an error has happened in the past.

If you see further errors from the device then it would be worth investigating the cause further.

Note that in the summary view the ECC field you are looking at is actually "Volatile Uncorr. ECC", i.e. it's the error count not the ECC enabled/disabled flag. If ECC is disabled it will say "N/A".

Comment: Is a reboot of the node necessary after resetting the error count?

Comment: @ritter reboot is not necessary after resetting ECC counter